# How to drag , drop and hold the element for sometime using javascript

Tags: javascript, selenium, drag-and-drop

i have a salesforce application which i am automating using selenium and i am implementing javascript for drag and drop. The problem is the moment i drop my src element on target it gets dropped somewhere else , manually we need to hold element on target for couple of seconds to fix it on the target. Do we have a code for holding element on target for few seconds.

this is below code that works for drag and drop for me , how can i hold src element on tgt

```
         final String java_script =
                   var src=arguments[0],tgt=arguments[1];var dataTransfer={dropEffe" +
                  "ct:'',effectAllowed:'all',files:[],items:{},types:[],setData:fun" +
                  "ction(format,data){this.items[format]=data;this.types.append(for" +
                  "mat);},getData:function(format){return this.items[format];},clea" +
                  "rData:function(format){}};var emit=function(event,target){var ev" +
                "t=document.createEvent('Event');evt.initEvent(event,true,false);" +
                "evt.dataTransfer=dataTransfer;target.dispatchEvent(evt);};emit('" +
                    "dragstart',src);emit('dragenter',tgt);emit('dragover',tgt);emit(" +
                   "'drop',tgt); emit('dragend',src); emit('dragleave' , src) ";

                     ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript(java_script, src, tgt);
```

Advanced thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try using Robot framework for drag and drop.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html

https://www.guru99.com/using-robot-api-selenium.html

Comment: i already tried robot framework method for drag and drop but it doesnt work , only JS script works